# How to Inject @Alternative with CDI from WAR into EJB Module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, ear

I want to let CDI "pick up" an Alternative Class as Implementation of an Interface.

While everything is bundles in a EAR the Alternative Implementation will be in the war file and the rest (Class injecting the Interfaces, the Interface, "Default" Implementation of the Interfaces) will be in the ejb jar.

Here some code to illustrate it:

**EJB Module:**

```
public interface I {}
```

```
public class C implements I {}
```

```
public class A {
  @Inject I var

  public void test() {
    System.out.println(var instanceof C); // I want to have here as Result: false
  }
}
```

**WAR Module:**

```
@Alternative
public class D implements I {}
```

Setting the beans.xml in the war file did not help..

Comment: You added the alternative section to beans.xml correct?

Comment: Yes, but the beans.xml of the WAR Module does not seem to effect the CDI decisions in the ejb-jar which has its own beans.xml which i can not change.

Comment: Yep, correct, because the ejb-jar can't actually see the classes in the war. If you were going the other direction you'd be golden. Which server are you using?

Comment: I am using Glassfish 3.1

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, i use 3.1.2

Comment: hm, I'm out of ideas atm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the structure that you are describing, there is no way to obtain the desired injection.

The EJB classloader will never be able to access the classes inside the WAR , hence the injection will never consider the alternative implementation.

A solution is possible if you are willing to alterate the EAR structure, placing the alternative (D) in a lib/jar , along with the appropriare `beans.xml`. The D class will become visible to your EJB and to your WAR, and the injection shoul proceed as desired.

#### EDIT

The solution you posted, which I descibe here, is almost working.

```
EAR
  - ejb-module-1.jar 
     - A.class (@Inject I)
     - I.class
     - C.class (@Stateless implements I)
     - META-INF/beans.xml
  - ejb-module-2.jar
     - D.class (@Alternative @Stateless implements I)
     - META-INF/beans.xml (<alternatives><class>D</class></alternative>)
  - app.war
     - calls A.test()
     - WEB-INF/beans.xml
```

The only catch is that you misplaced the `beans.xml` alternative declaration.

The CDI specification (1.1, but applicable as well to the previous implementation) states at chapter 5.1 that:

> An alternative is not available for injection, lookup or EL resolution
>   to classes or JSP/JSF pages in a module unless the module is a bean
>   archive and the alternative is explicitly selected in that bean
>   archive.

In other words, you must select the alternative *in the same module of the class which uses the bean*.

Here is the revised (and working) structure:

```
EAR
  - ejb-module-1.jar 
     - A.class (@Inject I)
     - I.class
     - C.class (@Stateless implements I)
     - META-INF/beans.xml (<alternatives><class>D</class></alternative>)
  - ejb-module-2.jar
     - D.class (@Alternative @Stateless implements I)
     - META-INF/beans.xml (empty <beans></beans>)
  - app.war
     - calls A.test()
     - WEB-INF/beans.xml (empty <beans></beans>)
```

Also remember that, although for standard beans the alternative selection works *only for the module in in witch the alternative is declared in `beans.xml`*, the same is not true for EJBs. So your `D` alternative, (being `@Stateless`) is valid for the entire application.

Comment: I did so and the old EJB-Jar is seen by the new EJB-Jar, because it get an Error from weld when i remove the @Alternative annotation, but even with the correct beans.xml inside the new EJB-Jar the old class is picked up..

Comment: Need more info to debug the whole situation... could you post: the complete EAR structure, the beans.xml both in the EJB jar and in the LIB jar. thanks

Comment: I made a minimal example containing everything:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9575658/Example-SO-1.zip

Comment: Thanks for you anwser but my problem is that i cannot change the beans.xml inside "ejb-module-1.jar". So there seem not to be a solution for me.. I will use a singleton startup bean that "injects" itself into a static field in class A.

Answer (score 2):

Since CDI 1.1. you can use @Priority so your alternative is discoverd in a global context - see here [Dependency injection and programmatic lookup](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#alternatives)

And if you use @Priority you do not need to declare the alternative in the beans.xml - see here [Using Alternatives in CDI Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv002.htm)